# Google calendar on Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-calendar-api

I am on Android Studio 2.0, latest emulator version. I still can't use the emulator to test calendar event scheduling (e.g. content://com.android.calendar/... or content://calendar/... for older SDKs).

What is my best option at the moment to move some of my tests from the physical device to a development workstation?

Comment: try genimotion software to test google calender

Comment: @DarjiJigar: https://www.genymotion.com/pricing-and-licensing/ :(

Comment: try bluestack,duos software

Comment: http://getintopc.com/softwares/emulators/genymotion-android-emulator-free-download/

Comment: same issue. emulator 2.0 is not able to load my contacts and calendars. Genymotion works ok though

Answer (score 0):

Install CalDAV adapter from an APK inside the emulator and set it up against any CalDAV server (Google's included).

Answer (score 0):

Add E-mail with Outlook  account .. its Exchange.. which means there will calendar-sync .. and calendar will work with you..

Answer (score -1):

To test your calendar-related code within the emulator, you first need to have a calendar. Try to sync with your own Google calendar.

Check http://www.grokkingandroid.com/using-a-google-account-in-the-emulator/

[**Edited**] It only works only for paid Google Apps users. Workaround is use 3d party accounts (ex. samuelhaddad.com/2015/06/16/add-a-calendar-on-android-emulator).

The best solution your tests should directly populate calendar with data.

Comment: I don't see it use Google Calendar integration with the built-in Calendar app.. do you? Can you get it to work?

Comment: Indeed, it only works only for paid Google Apps users. Workaround is use 3d party accounts (ex. http://samuelhaddad.com/2015/06/16/add-a-calendar-on-android-emulator/)